# Vue 2 - use same form for adding new and editing

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have following template:

```
<template>

    <div>
        <form @submit="save">

            <div class="field">
                <label class="label">Name</label>
                <div class="control">
                    <input class="input" type="text" placeholder="Name" :value="book.title">
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="field">
                <label class="label">Name</label>
                <div class="control">
                    <input class="input" type="text" placeholder="Name" :value="book.author">
                </div>
            </div>

        </form>
    </div>

</template>

<script>

    export default {

        data() {
            return {
                book : {}
            }
        },
        methods: {
            save() {

            }
        },
        created() {
            if(this.$store.state.book != 'undefined'){
                this.book = this.$store.state.book;
            }
        },
        computed: {}

    }

</script>

<style></style>
```

So far everything works fine if the book is pass with the **this.$store.state.book**, but if this is not passed the form is failing, with the error message:

** Error in render function: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'title' of undefined"**

I thought that passing the empty object would dynamically bind the book object and auto create the params.

Is it possible to use the same form for both adding new and editing?

Comment: Why don't you just create a book object with empty values for title and author?  An empty object won't have any properties so you should expect the TypeError.

Comment: I thought about that, but it seems a bit of a repeating, since I will have to make all value in the initial book object, and I kinda try to avoid this if possible. If it isn't, I guess I gonna go with that.

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code, and all you have to do is remove the 'quotes' from 'undefined'. Obviously, it's a string as is, and not a js thing.